# How to find multiple values in array?

Tags: c#, arrays

My code below looks only for one letter, how can I look for combination of letters? For ex.:  to find letters "ac" in my array and to output them to `textBox2`

```
string[] alphabet = new string[] { "a", "b", "c"};
for (int letter = 0; letter < alphabet.Length; letter++)
{
    if (textBox1.Text == alphabet[letter])
    textBox2.Text = alphabet[letter];
}
```

Comment: Do you want to check if all symbols in `textBox1.Text` are in the `alphabet`?

Comment: It's not clear, how is ""ac"" related to your array?

Comment: @Andrei yes, and output them to textbox2;

Comment: @LittleFox: what do you want to output? If all are in the `string[]`, do you want to ouput the complete string[]? If so, what is the desired result? Mabye: `string.Join(",", alphabet )`

Answer (score 3):

I guess you want to check if only letters of the array are entered in the textbox:

```
bool valid = textBox1.Text.All(c => alphabet.Contains(c.ToString()));
```

if it was a `char[]` you could write:

```
bool valid = textBox1.Text.All(alphabet.Contains);
```

Then you could also use `Enumerable.Except` to get the set difference:

```
var notValidLetters = textBox1.Text.Except(alphabet);
textBox2.Text = "Following are not valid letters: " + String.Join(", ", notValidLetters);
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering your problem is "Find both `a` and `c` from the given string `ac`";

```
string[] alphabet = new string[] { "a", "b", "c"};
        for (int letter = 0; letter < alphabet.Length; letter++)
        {
            if (textBox1.Text.Any(alphabet[letter]))
                textBox2.Text += alphabet[letter];
        }
```